# Reformatting page is failed when appending new item to navbar in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to embed an item to Navbar dynamically using below code

```
$('#addForm').live('click', function() {
    $('<li><a href="#" data-href="a" data-icon="grid">Form ' +   ($(this).parent().find('li').length) + '</a></li>').insertBefore($(this));
    $('#frmNav').navbar();
 });​
```

And you can also check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3RJuX/398/) fiddle. I have tried all solutions given in SO as of now. None is working for me.. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

***JS***

```
$('#addForm').live('click', function() {
     var textA = 'Form ' + $(this).parent().find('li').length;   

    var li = $("<li>");
    var a = $("<a>")
        .attr("data-href","a")
        .attr("data-icon","grid")
        .attr("href","#")
        .text(textA );

   $(a).appendTo(li)     

   $(li).insertBefore($(this));

   $(li).navbar();

});​
```

You need to call `navBar()` for new element